# Send variable to $_POST without live search

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have modified a working live search script to include a combo box. I want the live search box to work as normal. I need the combo box when a selection is made to pass the selection in the form of a variable to the livecompsearch.php script. I don't want the combo box to search anything just to be able to use the variable if and when needed such as using $_POST['query2']. I have omitted much of the code from the php script as it is not really needed here, I only want to output the variable for now.
I am planning on using the dropdown as an option to search different columns in in a table by selecting one of the options first then to start typing what they are looking for in the live search box.

```
Testp.php

    <div class="line">
        <div class="box margin-bottom">
            <div class="margin">
                <div class="s-12 m-6 l-12">
                <input type="text" name="search_box" id="search_box" class="searchbox" placeholder="Enter your live search here..." />
                <select name="Search_Option" id="Search_Option" class="searchbox" style="width: auto;">
                <?php
                    $options = array(
                    '0'=> 'All',
                    '1'=> 'Played',
                    '2'=> 'Scheduled',
                    '3'=> 'Cancelled'
                    );
                    $selected = 'Select';
                        foreach($options as $option=> $title){
                            if($selected==$option){
                                echo '<option value="'.htmlspecialchars($option).'" selected="selected">'.ucfirst($title).'</option>';
                            }else{
                                echo '<option value="'.htmlspecialchars($option).'">'.ucfirst($title).'</option>';
                            }
                        }
                ?>
                </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    load_data(0);
    load_data(1);
    
    function load_data(page, query = '', query2 = '0')
    {
      $.ajax({
        url:"includes/livecompsearch.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{page:page, query:query, query2:query2},
        success:function(data)
        {
          $('#dynamic_content').html(data);
        }
      });
    }

    $(document).on('click', '.page-link', function(){
      var page = $(this).data('page_number');
      var query = $('#search_box').val();
      load_data(page, query);
    });

    $('#search_box').keyup(function(){
      var query = $('#search_box').val();
      load_data(1, query);
    });

    $('#Search_Option').change(function(){
      var query2 = $('#Search_Option').val();
      load_data(0, 1, query2);
    });

  });
</script>
```

livecompsearch.php

```
<?php

echo '  <p><strong>Variable: </strong>['.$_POST['query2'].']</p>'; 

?>
```

Comment: I can not tell what you are actually trying to ask here. Changing the selected option, calls your `load_data` function. If that is not what you want to do in that case - well do something else then? You know how to make AJAX requests and send data to the server (that is what happens in `load_data` already), so if you want to make a different kind of request in that place … do it?

Comment: When a selection is made from the dropdown option it begins a live search, I don't want it to search anything, just put the selected value (0,1,2,3) into variable query2 so that it can be accessed using the $_POST['query2'] in the livecompsearch.php script.

Comment: You are targeting a script that does nothing but echo back the value of the `query2` parameter - in what way is that a “live search”? And, again, if the functionality currently performed by `load_data` is not what you want inside the change event handler - well then replace it with something else. Where is the actual _problem_ with that?

Comment: You are targeting a script that does nothing but echo back the value of the query2 parameter - in what way is that a “live search”?  I have obmitted the rest of the code in that file because for this application it is not needed, I just want to make sure that when the code is run it can echo the result of the dropdown selection.

Answer (score 1):

Hey so I might be misunderstanding your problem but I think you could either just use an if-statement so that if you only change the HTML if you get a certain result from the PHP.

Or better yet just don't have it fire if you change the combo-box.

Put the `var query = $('#search_box').val()` and `var query2 = $('#Search_Option').val();` in the `load_data` function just before `$.ajax({` then send it in that way.

Get rid of the `query` parameters obviously then just put the function call in your event handlers.

If you keep it all in one function then when it is triggered it will send the values of what the input is at that moment which I think is what you're going for.

Comment: you understood my question correct. will pop back later and let you know the outcome. appreciated

Comment: That's ok I'm glad I could help.
No offence but I'm going to hazard a guess and say you're quite new to this so try playing around with `print_r($_POST)` or `var_dump($_POST)` on the PHP side.